# Political Change: "Polity" or "Policy"?

Tags: word-usage

Before the transformation from the old polity to the new polity which is the republican and secular regimes, women had to cover their hair and faces with a hijab in accordance with the law.

My english teacher who is orginally American told me that in that sentence I need to use the word of policy instead of polity. But when I look up the definition of the word of polity, it implies that "a form or process of civil government or constitution". So, in the sentence which is top, I'd like to imply that it is the form of civil government that is changing. What is the wrong with polity to use in that context. If it is wrong usage in that context , can you give me some usage of the word of polity. Thank you in advance.

Comment: From wikipedia: A polity is a **general term for any kind of political entity** -- group of people that are collectively united by a self-reflected cohesive force, which includes policies that are **a statement of intent**, and is implemented as a procedure or protocol. So a polity is much broader and not limited to policy. If you wanna be precise, policy is what you should use, and is understood by anyone, unlike polity

Comment: If you attribute the change to a shift from an authoritarian, theological regime to a republican, secular regime, I think *polity* is entirely appropriate. But if you attribute the change to a new stance by a government which remains essentially the same, then *policy* would be more appropriate.

Comment: I wouldn't use *polity* because many people (even native speakers) will not know what it means. How about [status quo](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/status-quo)? It is not specific to politics, but in context it will be understood.

Comment: @StoneyB What exactly i meant was a shift (transmision) from a theological regime to a republican, secular regime. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically I think **polity** probably is closer to being correct here, because the regime is a [politically organized unit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polity); the regime is not [a course of action or an overall plan](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/policy).

However, neither word looks very good here because of the way the sentence is structured and because of the way in which we usually use the word *polity*.  *Polity* is a rather specialized word that usually means something like "something that is a single entity within the context of politics."  Some examples,

> [The polity is here conceived of as the highest order sociopolitical unit in the region in question.](https://books.google.com/books?id=oP48AAAAIAAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=polity&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q=polity&f=false)  (In other words, "The 'polity' I'm talking about here is the largest-scale political structure in the area."
>
> [The people of a polity might reasonably wonder about the control they have over the historical drift and flux of their culture.](https://books.google.com/books?id=kRQz9I2OfKMC&lpg=PP1&dq=polity&pg=PA53#v=onepage&q=polity&f=false)
>     (In other words, "The people who make up a political unit might wonder about the control they have..."
>
> [It is the search for attitudes and beliefs among the landowners who dominated the medieval polity...](https://books.google.com/books?id=pyfaYFThAPcC&lpg=PP1&dq=polity&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q=polity&f=false)  (In other words, "among the landowners who dominated the politics of the body of the people".)

So it doesn't really make sense to say "the republican and secular regimes are the new polity".  *Polity* doesn't mean "a regime"; it means something more like "the whole political structure of the country" or "all the people, considered as a political entity".

If I had to rewrite your sentence, I would use something like

> **Before the transformation from the old regime to the new republican, secular regime, women had to cover their hair and faces with a hijab in accordance with the law.**

Comment: Thank you very much for commen, It is been very useful and it made me clear.